# remove legend column alias name from legend time series graph in grafana 8

Tags: grafana

I have a query in grafana using postgres as data source as such:

```
SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC('month', obsolete_date) as "time",
  product_type,
  count(product_type) as "_"
FROM
  evergreen
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
```

On grafana I get the following graph:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

As one can see, the underscore is present in all legend values of my graph, whatever i type as alias for a column it will appear as the legend. I don't want that, I want to just have the different values of the column plotted as text for my legend. How can i do that ? i tried regex value mappings on grafana but it did not work for me.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5gzd.png

Comment: It seems that `_` is count for product type from:

       ```(...)
        count(product_type) as "_"
       (...)```
Did you consider removing `as "_"` part?